# Table header not printing in every page in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Basically I have a html page to be printed on A4 sheets. Actually the HTML page is an invoice, which has the company info on the top and some terms and conditions on the bottom and we wanted these details to get printed on every page while printing.
For that I kept the whole body in a `<table>` tag and wrapped the company info in a `<thead>` tag and the terms and conditions in a `<tfoot>` tag.

But we have observed that if the height of the `<thead>` is greater than 250px, `<thead>` is not printing on all pages and if it is less that 250px it is getting printed on all pages.

Tried many things but without any result. Did not find anything relevant in google too.